# Alexa developer console doesn't update endpoint or allows any connection

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, ngrok

So basically i'm attending a lecture in university where we develope an Alexa skill. We got introduced into everything and we need to develope the skill using our own provided backend and a ngrok tunnel. The Python code and the .json got provided by the professor.

My problem is that i am not able to get a connection to the developer console and i'm not able to code anything because it just doesn't start. The method is working because everyone else is using it, it's just at my machines.. This happens at home, at university and even at my partners place.

Here are some pictures:

[instering new endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V02NI.png)

[Saving model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSC1C.png)

[Building new model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXBes.png)

[endpoint after building and testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOmhU.png)

At this point i don't know what to do, i asked the professor several times who couldn't help me at all with this problem. Other students are not having this problem. Account permissions are on administrator, i only get notifications about payment & tax informations even tho i have set everything on private and non profit. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are you looking for code (but in Python) for this API?   https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/alexaforbusiness/AlexaForBusinessClient.html

Comment: No i'm looking for help establishing a working connection so i can start coding for my project..